# [__NSCFString JSONValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x78e1000

Tags: iphone, json

I am new for iphone development.
Here i encounter problem in executing my code

```
-[__NSCFString JSONValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x78e1000
2013-01-08 09:43:21.194 loanjson[655:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString JSONValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x78e1000'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c8d012 0x10cae7e 0x1d184bd 0x1c7cbbc 0x1c7c94e 0x2b34 0xbd0e59 0xbcef22 0xbd016a 0xbceedd 0xbcf055 0xb1c338 0x460aa81 0x4609d33 0x4647e3a 0x1c2f8fd 0x46484bc 0x4648435 0x45323a0 0x1c10f3f 0x1c1096f 0x1c33734 0x1c32f44 0x1c32e1b 0x1be77e3 0x1be7668 0x1265c 0x2322 0x2255)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

I dont know why this error comes , I am using JSON request and response ,I already check all the JSON value to parse in the NSString
This is my code in my .m file

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    [connection release];

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    self.responseData = nil;

    NSArray* latestLoans = [(NSDictionary*)[responseString JSONValue] objectForKey:@"loans"];
    [responseString release];
    NSLog(@"%@",latestLoans);


    //choose a random loan
    NSDictionary* loan = [latestLoans objectAtIndex:0];


    //fetch the data
    NSNumber* fundedAmount = [loan objectForKey:@"funded_amount"];
    NSNumber* loanAmount = [loan objectForKey:@"loan_amount"];
    float outstandingAmount = [loanAmount floatValue] - [fundedAmount floatValue];

    NSString* name = [loan objectForKey:@"name"];
    NSLog(@"====:%@",(NSDictionary*)[loan objectForKey:@"location"]);
    NSString* country = [(NSDictionary*)[loan objectForKey:@"location"] objectForKey:@"country"];

    //set the text to the label
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Latest loan: %@ from %@ needs another $%.2f, please help",
                  name,country,outstandingAmount
                  ];
}
```

Please guide me,
Thanks

Comment: Add breakpoint in that method & check in which line you getting error...

Comment: @ vishal, i have already check and get error in NSArray* latestLoans = [(NSDictionary*)[responseString JSONValue] objectForKey:@"loans"];  this line

Comment: please NSLog the NSString, I think it's null

Comment: @Midhun MP, i debug with NSLOg and null comes with mutableArray data and without it, there is above error occurs

Comment: @kirtiavaiya: I mean `responseData` will be null, please `NSLog(@"responseString = %@",responseData);`

Comment: @MidhunMP If `responseString` were `nil`, the call would fail silently.

Comment: @MidhunMP calling a method on null does not raise any exceptions! i don't think null can be of any issue in this case!

Comment: @NateChandler: sorry, I mean responceData

Comment: @cyberpawn: sorry, It's my fault. I mean responceData

Comment: @MidhunMP I am using #define kLatestKivaLoansURL @"http://api.kivaws.org/v1/loans/search.json?status=fundraising" api access and already define in viewdidload method, and my responsestring is not null,it comes with loan data directly from above URL request

Answer (score 0):

`NSString` does not have a method named `JSONValue`. That's why its throwing unrecognized selector. You can use a third party Json framework like [Json Kit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) for parsing json.

If using SBJson Framewrok then try parsing this way!

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
[connection release];

NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
self.responseData = nil;
SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];  
NSDictionary *jsonArray = (NSDictionary *) [parser objectWithString:responseString error:nil]; 
NSArray *latestLoans = [jsonArray valueForKey:@"loans"];
[responseString release];
[parser release];
NSLog(@"%@",latestLoans);


//choose a random loan
NSDictionary* loan = [latestLoans objectAtIndex:0];


//fetch the data
NSNumber* fundedAmount = [loan objectForKey:@"funded_amount"];
NSNumber* loanAmount = [loan objectForKey:@"loan_amount"];
float outstandingAmount = [loanAmount floatValue] - [fundedAmount floatValue];

NSString* name = [loan objectForKey:@"name"];
NSLog(@"====:%@",(NSDictionary*)[loan objectForKey:@"location"]);
NSString* country = [(NSDictionary*)[loan objectForKey:@"location"] objectForKey:@"country"];

//set the text to the label
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Latest loan: %@ from %@ needs another $%.2f, please help",
              name,country,outstandingAmount
              ];
}
```

Comment: probaly he is using SBJSON parser.

Comment: if thats the case then please make sure if you are properly adding SBJSON framework and importing the required classes!

Comment: @MidhunMP ,@cyberpawn yes Midhun MP I am using SBJSON parser and also I also import it into my .m

Comment: @cyberpawn i also import all the JSON.h class file from my SBJSON in to .m file

Comment: @kirtiavaiya i have updated my answer, please try parsing json this way!

Comment: Thnks all i solve my error, un-expectedly my JSON bundle was not in my reference adding, but it was in test project,

Comment: :) thats wonderful. @kirtiavaiya please accept the answer if it helped you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `iOS 5` or later then you can use this

```
NSError* error;
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
 NSArray* latestLoans = [json objectForKey:@"loans"]
```

---

I think you are using 3rd party JSON parser might be [**SBJSON**](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/api/3.2/). Please include this kit and use **[NSString_SBJsonParsing](http://sbjson.org/api/3.2/Categories/NSString+NSString_SBJsonParsing.html)** category's `JSONValue` method.